# Query Error PHP when the connection is established

Tags: php

I don't understand why i get this error, i can't understand what's wrong..

**The Error:** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

**This is the code:**

```
/**
 * @category SQL Connection
 * @description Connect to SQL Database
 */
    $conn = new mysqli('server-0275.whmpanels.com', '---', '---', '---') or die(mysqli_error());

/**
 * @sub-category Functions
 * @description Main Functions
 */

    // If it's home
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') {
        /**
         * @function Users
         * @description Count registered users
         */
            function users() {
                $rs = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `maxUsers` FROM `vrp_users`");
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
                    return $row['maxUsers'];
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: You have an error with `or die(mysqli_error())`. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$conn` is not accessible in the `users()` function as it was defined outside of the function. You can either access the global variable like this (not ideal - read up about why you shouldn't do this):

```
function users() {
    global $conn;
    $rs = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `maxUsers` FROM `vrp_users`");
    //rest of code...
}
```

Or pass the `$conn` variable into the function

```
function users($conn) {
    $rs = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `maxUsers` FROM `vrp_users`");
    //rest of code...
}
```